# Writing multiple if-else statements in C++ and branching using the rand() function

Tags: c++

The question reads:

> We would like to be able to classify new animals they are discovered in the wild. We will use the `rand()` function to generate random integers (0 or 1) to represent the No or Yes
>   answers respectively to a series of questions. We can then use the answers to classify animals as either:
>
> - Insects
> - Reptiles
> - Birds
> - Mammals
>
> In each case, the questions continue until an identification is made. For each question asked, a random value is needed for the answer. To identify each animal, use a nested `if`-`else` structure.

Here are a few sample program runs with their outputs. Each example is a distinct program run.

```
Random Animal Generator

Is the animal a vertibrate? Yes – Not Insect
Is the animal warm-blooded? Yes – Not Reptile
Can the animal fly? Yes – The animal is a Bird!
```

---

```
Random Animal Generator

Is the animal a vertibrate? No – The animal is an Insect!
```

---

```
Random Animal Generator

Is the animal a vertibrate? Yes – Not Insect
Is the animal warm-blooded? No – The animal is a Reptile!
```

I’m so confused. How do I generate all the `else if` statements to work and answer in order? How do I make them answer by yes or no, then make them answer again yes or no, etc.? Also how do I make them come out randomly with the `rand()` function?

Code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

main () { 
    char Answer; 
    cout<<" Random Animal Generator\n"; 
    cout << "Is the animal a vertibrate?(1=Yes/0=No)? "; 
    cin >> Answer; 

    if(Answer == '1') 
        cout << "Not Insect \n"; 
    else (Answer== '0') 
        cout<<"The animal is an Insect!\n"; 

    cout<<endl; 
    system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main () 
{
char Answer;

cout<<" Random Animal Generator\n";

cout << "Is the animal a vertibrate?(1=Yes/0=No)? ";
cin >> Answer;

if(Answer == '1')
cout << "Not Insect \n";

else (Answer== '0')
cout<<"The animal is an Insect!\n";
cout<<endl;
system("pause");
}

Comment: thats the code i have so far ^^^^ this thing wont let me put the whole thing up for some reason?

Comment: First, get rid of the [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). Second, you aren't supposed to get input, you're supposed to generate an answer randomly.

Comment: I inserted and fixed the code for you, and made the test cases easier to read.

Comment: #include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main () {  
    char Answer;  
 return rand();
    cout<<" Random Animal Generator\n";  
    cout << "Is the animal a vertibrate?(1=Yes/0=No)? ";  
    cin >> Answer;

Comment: if(Answer == '1')  
        cout << "Not Insect \n";  
    else if (Answer== '0')  
        cout<<"The animal is an Insect!\n";  

 cout<<"Is the animal warm-blooded?\n";
 cin>> Answer;

 if (Answer=='1')
  cout<<"Not Reptile\n";
 else if (Answer=='0')
  cout<<"The animal is a Reptile!\n";

 cout<<"Can the animal fly?\n";
 cin>> Answer;

 if (Answer=='1')
  cout<<"The animal is a Bird!\n";
 else if (Answer=='0')
  cout<<"The animal is a Mammal!\n";

 
    cout<<endl;  
    return(0);  
} 

sorry had to write code in 2 parts characters ran out

Comment: thnx guys! rewrote the code above sorry had to post in 2 parts characters ran out,  need help with how to use the rand() to generate the random questions? do i put the rand() on the bottom or on top?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int getRandomAnswer()
{ // code here to return a 1 or 0 randomly
}


main () { 
    cout<<" Random Animal Generator\n"; 
    cout << "Is the animal a vertebrate?"; 

    if(getRandomAnswer() == 1) 
    {
        cout << "Yes - Not Insect \n"; 
        cout << "Is the animal warm blooded?"
        if (getRandomAnswer() == 1)
        {
          // Code for "warm blooded" case goes here
        }
        else
        {
          // Code for "not warm blooded" case goes here
        }
     }
    else
    {
       cout<<"No. The animal is an Insect!\n"; 
    }

    cout<<endl; 
}
```

Also, do not use `system("pause");` under any circumstances. If you want to wait for a keypress, then do that. But you have no way to know whether there is a command called `pause` on other people's machines or, if so, what it does. On my machine, for example, there's a command called `pause` that pauses the coolant pump on my home reactor. Imagine the potential harm if I had tested your code on my machine!

Comment: I don't think I did. All I did is show him where he misunderstood the question and showed him how to nest. I didn't give him the code to generate the random numbers or continue the if chain.

Comment: I agree; this is about as little you can go in the right direction past what the OP had to give a good hint. I like the coolant pump story, too.

Comment: @Seva, this looks like a good homework question answer, based on the code the OP provided. David, +1. Nice pointer without doing all the work.

Answer (score 0):

The C library has a function `rand()` that returns a random number from 0 to RAND_MAX. Now,  you want a random number that's a zero or a one. What's a good function that takes a random number and returns a 0/1 with equal probability (or very close to equal)?

Think of properties of natural numbers. You need a property that about half the numbers has and the other half has not.

Comment: To everybody BUT USER1467896, do NOT answer this question.  Let USER1467896 answer it (this IS homework).  Too many times I see people ANSWER the homework.  "The answer is 42" - that's NOT the point of helping people with homework.

Comment: do you mean rand()%10 for example??

Comment: Similar :) You need a zero/one.