# How do you use rand() function to ask different questions each time?

Tags: c++

What code is used for this type of problem? Also where do you place the code for the rand() in the top or bottom?

Comment: need help don't understand this chapter at all just trying to figure out how to make it kind of loop without using the loop instead using the random to continuosly ask questions.

Comment: What chapter? please provide some links to what you are talking about.

Comment: here is a link, what i mean to ask is in these examples they have switch and if else statements, so i want to know how to use a rand() code to make the yes no questions be asked in different order ---> http://www.functionx.com/cpp/Lesson09.htm

Comment: You need to edit your question so that it can stand alone. What code are you talking about? Top or bottom of what? And what are the "different questions" you're talking about? (You're referring to an assignment nobody else can see and you haven't put any details or a [link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111748/writing-multiple-if-else-statements-in-c-and-branching-using-the-rand-functi) in your question.)

Comment: Try to make a flowchart of this problem first on paper. Will help you to conclude out the logic easily.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you call `srand(time(NULL));` once (and only once) as the program is starting up.

To ask different questions, you'd normally get a random number with `rand`, reduce it to the range of the number of questions, and use that to select one of the questions.

Comment: His question is referring to a specific use case he hasn't explained. He wants the random numbers to provide different answers to yes or no questions. His program logic will then ask different follow up questions based on the answers to previous questions.