# srand is too slow in C++ it return same number

Tags: c++, random, time, srand

I'm just trying to have simply RndInt(limit) function that will return random numbers with a limit as limit.

```
    cout << "Enter higher limit of random range:" ;
 cin >> limit;
 while(limit != 0)

{
//        RndInt(limit);
    cout << "Random number smaller than " << limit << " is " << RndInt(limit) << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    cout << "Other random number smaller than " << limit << " is " << RndInt(limit) << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    cout << "There is " << RndInt(limit) << " ways I love you" <<endl ;
    cout << "Enter higher limit of random range:" ;
    cin >> limit;
}
return 0;
}

int RndInt(int limit)
{
srand(time(&base));
int rndnumber;
rndnumber=rand()%limit;
base+=100;
return rndnumber;
}
```

I'm having problem to make RndInt subsequent calls display different integer. When I debug its fine subsequent calls to RndInt(limit) give different value. But when I try to run it without cin.get() for pause I get same numbers in all three calls. I figured out that problem is that seed is in the same second.

My question is how to make calls to RndInt return different values without pause. What to do to srand function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use rand() function to ask different questions each time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112873/how-do-you-use-rand-function-to-ask-different-questions-each-time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not call `srand()` every time you want a random number. Call `srand()` *once* at the start of your program, and then call `rand()` for each number.

Comment: Yes, think of "srand" as "seed-rand": It seeds the random number generator. Give it the same value each time, and you'll get the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers with each subsequent call to rand() (in one thread).